# Integrating to find volume

Tags: calculus, integration

I found a problem on a worksheet.

Determine the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the region bounded by
$$y=\left(x-1\right)(x-3)^2$$ and the x-axis about the y-axis.

I got this for the integral:
$$2\pi\int_1^3{x(x-1)(x-3)^2}dx$$
$$=2\pi\int_1^3{(x^4-7x^3+15x^2-9x)}dx$$
$$=2\pi\left[\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{7}{4}x^4+5x^3-\frac{9}{2}x^2\right]_0^3$$

The answer I get is 
$$2\pi\left(\frac{24487}{20} + \frac{11}{12}\right)$$
$$=\frac{18379}{15}$$

I am certain this method is wrong. Are we not supposed to use the shell method? How do I fix the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your volume integral expression is correct. You just did not integrate it right

$$2\pi\int_1^3{x(x-1)(x-3)^2}dx$$

$$=2\pi \left[\frac{1}{5}x^5-\frac{7}{4}x^4+5x^3-\frac{9}{2}x^2 \right]_1^3$$

$$=2\pi \left( \frac{242}{5}-140+130-36\right)=\frac{24}{5}\pi$$

Comment: yes, an algebraic mistake...